# Finding a match in an array using strcmp

Tags: c, matrix, cstring, strcmp

im trying to compare words of an array using strcmp.Im trying to get each word that appears more than once in the array to print out only once, so i can determine the number of unique words.I know what its doing wrong as when it searches the array it prints out each copy it finds, for example if the word "the" is in the array 4 times, it will print out 'the' 3 times and when `string1` goes to the next location where 'the' is, it will print out 2 times and so on.

Comment: Bob the builder! Can he fix it? Bob the builder! No he can't :(

Comment: Two questions: 1. Why is this question tagged with 'cstring'? 2. Why are you using `strcmp()` to compare strings in C++? `std::string` has a perfectly good `operator ==`!

Comment: i dont want to use string objects for this program

Comment: This code makes no sense to me. I suggest using more descriptive variable names.

Comment: @Bob the builder: What is wrong with `std::string`? You're writing C++!

Comment: another question, how is string1[] declared? it looks a bit suspect your line for ( x = 0;x <= 15;x++) since a common error is to write <= when it should have been < if you declared it string1[15]

Comment: its declared as this... char string1[16] = ""

Comment: @Anders K: That's a good question. It looks like `words` is a 2D array of `char*`, which makes `string1` look like an array of `char*` and the call to `strlen(string1)` very dubious. `std::string` is certainly the way to go here (coupled with `std::set` for isolating the unique entries, as suggested in [Benjamin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459438/finding-a-match-in-an-array-using-strcmp/7459457#7459457).

Comment: @Bob the builder: Providing all of the declarations in your code snipped would be really helpful. That assignment looks dubious, too.

Comment: well this assignment specifies that i cannot use c++ string objects

Comment: Ah... the classic "unique words" homework assignment, eh?

Comment: char string1[16] = "".each words is maximum 16 character long

Comment: What happens when your file includes the word 'piezoelectrically'?

Comment: lets pretend for arguments sake that each word is at most 16 chars

Comment: @quasiverse: Bob the Builder is a psychopath. If you're not careful, he might take a chainsaw along with him on a visit to your house.

Comment: Bob, it's okay if you want to use c-style strings and functions for this as a learning opportunity or because you have no choice. You tagged the question as C++ though. People are naturally going to suggest C++ strings, containers, and algorithms because this would make the problem solution trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good that you added declarations,

now from what it looks it seems as if words[][] is redundant and makes things unnecessary complicated. if you are only interested in getting unique words, instead just process what comes back from strtrok by building up a dictionary with the encountered words

a dictionary could be something as simple as a max sized array containing unique words, and an index that starts at 0 when array is empty, whenever strtok returns a word, go through the array and look for the word using your strcmp, if it doesn't exist add it at the end of the array then increment then index.

and bob is your uncle :)

Comment: My only suggestion would be a linked list instead of a large array.

Comment: so youre saying that i load an array with all the words, and compare that with what returned by strok?

Answer (score 2):

Convert your char arrays to `std::string` and instead of printing them, put them into an `std::set`.  Then print each element in the set.

Comment: i cant use string object for this program

Comment: Great answer if he can understand it. However I doubt he knows how to use `std::string` let alone `std::set`.

Comment: @Bob: Why?  If you're going to put arbitrary restrictions on yourself, then I'll vote to close your question as 'too localized', because this is not a real problem that a C++ programmer would ever face.

Comment: char string1[16] = "".each words is maximum 16 character long –

Comment: @Bob: That doesn't ensure that your words are only 16 characters, it simply results in access violations when they go over.  With std::string, you won't get access violations if it goes over, and you can safely check the length and take any corrective action necessary.

Comment: im reading from a file that has a maximum of 16 chars includeing the terminating char, so going overboard isnt as issue

Comment: @Bob: Okay.  Then I don't understand the purpose of your previous comment.

Comment: @Bob the builder: 'the terminating char'? What is that in a text file?